# Why am I getting an Uncaught Reference Error on a function that is defined

Tags: javascript, html

I created a set of img tags in the "game btn container" to act as buttons that I have added onclick, onmouseover, and onmouseout attributes to change the src and the active state(I took out onmouseout and onmouseover).  The games.js file is connected and has the function defined.  In fact, in the next segment of the HTML page, I have similar buttons that ARE working correctly, so why am I pulling an error here? 
Uncaught Reference Error: changeBtnActive is not defined at htmlImageElement.onclick(games.html:77) I've checked the spelling, I've cleared out the cache, I added a semicolon after the function statement...

```js
/** JS Code **/

    function changeBtnActive(button){
        alert("Yes!!!)");
        /*var gameBtns = $(".game-btn-img");
        for(var i=0; i < gameBtns.length; i++){
            var btnName = gameBtns[i].dataset.name;
            gameBtns[i].src = "assets/images/games/buttons/selector/" + btnName + "BtnUp.png";
            gameBtns[i].dataset.state = "inactive";
        }
        button.src = "assets/images/games/buttons/selector/" + button.dataset.string + "BtnActive.png";
        button.dataset.state = "active";*/
    }
    
    function changeBtnOver(button){
    
    }
    
       /* if (button.dataset.state != "active"){
            button.src = "assets/images/games/buttons/selector/" + button.dataset.string + "BtnOver.png";
        }*/
    
    
    function changeBtnOut(button){
        /*if (button.dataset.state != "active"){
            button.src = "assets/images/games/buttons/selector/" + button.dataset.string + "BtnUp.png";
        }*/
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    function changeSrcDown(button){
        switch(button.dataset.color){
            case "red":
                button.src = "assets/images/games/buttons/arcade/redBtnDown.png";
                break;
    
            case "white":
                button.src = "assets/images/games/buttons/arcade/whiteBtnDown.png";
                break;
    
            case "green":
                button.src = "assets/images/games/buttons/arcade/greenBtnDown.png";
                break;
        }
    }
    
    function changeSrcUp(button){
        switch(button.dataset.color){
            case "red":
                button.src = "assets/images/games/buttons/arcade/redBtnUp.png";
                break;
    
            case "white":
                button.src = "assets/images/games/buttons/arcade/whiteBtnUp.png";
                break;
    
            case "green":
                button.src = "assets/images/games/buttons/arcade/greenBtnUp.png";
                break;
        }
    }
```

```html
HTML Code

    
      <!-- Game Btn Container -->
      <div class="arcade-btn-container">
        <div class="container-fluid">
    
          <div class="row">
      
           <div class="col-md col-sm-4">
              <img class="game-btn-img" src="assets/images/games/buttons/selector/fitnessBtnUp.png" alt="btn1"  data-string="fitness" data-state="active" onclick="changeBtnActive(this);">
            </div>
      
            <div class="col-md col-sm-4">
              <img class="game-btn-img" src="assets/images/games/buttons/selector/tagBtnUp.png" alt="btn1" data-string="tag"
              data-state="inactive" onclick="changeBtnActive(this)">
            </div>
      
            <div class="col-md col-sm-4">
              <img class="game-btn-img" src="assets/images/games/buttons/selector/throwingBtnUp.png" alt="btn1" data-string="throwing"
              data-state="inactive" onclick="changeBtnActive(this)">
            </div>
      
            <div class="col-md col-sm-4">
              <img class="game-btn-img" src="assets/images/games/buttons/selector/kickingBtnUp.png" alt="btn1" data-string="kicking"
              data-state="inactive" onclick="changeBtnActive(this)">
            </div>
      
            <div class="col-md col-sm-4">
              <img class="game-btn-img" src="assets/images/games/buttons/selector/strikingBtnUp.png" alt="btn1" data-string="striking"
              data-state="inactive" onclick="changeBtnActive(this)">
            </div>
      
            <div class="col-md col-sm-4">
              <img class="game-btn-img" src="assets/images/games/buttons/selector/teamBtnUp.png" alt="btn1" data-string="team"
              data-state="inactive" onclick="changeBtnActive(this)">
            </div>
      
          </div>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    
    
    
      <!-- Middle Container -->
      <div class="middle-games-container">
    
        <div class="arcade-container-bkg">
          <img class="mid-games-bkg" src="assets/images/games/pixelBkg.png" alt="arcade-bkg">
        </div>
    
        <img class="arcade-splash" src="assets/images/games/arcadeSplash.png" alt="video-splash">
        <img class="arcade-img" src="assets/images/games/arcade.png" alt="arcade">
    
        <div class="arcade-controls-container">
          <img class="controls-btn" src="assets/images/games/buttons/arcade/whiteBtnUp.png" alt="white-btn" data-color="white"
            onmousedown="changeSrcDown(this)" onmouseup="changeSrcUp(this)" onmouseout="changeSrcUp(this)">
          <img class="controls-btn" src="assets/images/games/buttons/arcade/greenBtnUp.png" alt="green-btn" data-color="green"
            onmousedown="changeSrcDown(this)" onmouseup="changeSrcUp(this)" onmouseout="changeSrcUp(this)">
          <img class="controls-btn" src="assets/images/games/buttons/arcade/redBtnUp.png" alt="red-btn" data-color="red"
            onmousedown="changeSrcDown(this)" onmouseup="changeSrcUp(this)" onmouseout="changeSrcUp(this)">
        </div>
    
        <div id="joystick" class="joystick">
          <img class="joystick-img" src="assets/images/games/buttons/arcade/joystick.png" alt="joystick">
        </div>
    
      </div>
    
      <script src="js/games.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Use addEventListener instead of inline event handlers, and your problems will vanish.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go ahead and change it this morning.  However, can you just answer this for me, since I'm a beginner?  I came to my computer this morning after posting this last night, opened up the project folder and now the inline mouse functions work.   Like I never even had a problem.  I could have sworn that I restarted all of my apps last night as well to check if that was the problem.

Comment: The most common reason for this error is that the functions are not defined globally, they're inside a load handler or in some other function. Another common reason is a syntax error in the function, that makes it also undefined.